# Have {% csrf_token %} tag in template but no csrfmiddlewaretoken hidden value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using django.contrib.comments in Django, version is 1.6.1
then I have a form like this,

```
{% get_comment_form for mbean as form %}
<table>
  <form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post" class="aaa">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">
        <input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

but when I check my page source in HTML, I can't find `<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='uiwp7YkGi374HwnZqMRbCUmzyH38jDPI' />` in my source, and have

> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

error.

I also used `{% csrf_token %}` in other form of this template but still no "csrfmiddlewaretoken".

1. Is having no "csrfmiddlewaretoken" the reason why I have "CSRF
   verification failed. Request aborted" error ?
2. Can anyone give some help about what's wrong with my template?

Comment: Your template is good. The issue is either in your settings or in your view. Can you post the view code?

Comment: Here is my original `return render_to_response('suborder.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))` and then I followed Deshraj's help to change to `return render_to_response('suborder.html', RequestContext(request, locals()))`  and it works now. Thank you too, @spectras !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the {% csrf_token %} into your templates, you need to pass the RequestContext instance to the template while rendering it and then here you go. You can then use the csrf_token and also it will be visible in the source.

Sample Code snippet for sending the context instance while rendering a template:

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```